# ajax jquery.validate with stripe payment - combine js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [Stripe payment system](https://gist.github.com/1750368) to accept credit cards with jQuery validator for forms all with `ajax`.
This works for stripe and ajax but the validation doesnt work.
Here's `process.php` https://gist.github.com/1750375

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var payBtn = $('#paymentBtn').click(function(){
            Stripe.createToken({
                    number: $('.card_number').val(),
                    cvc: $('.card_cvc').val(),
                    exp_month: $('.card_expiry_month').val(), 
                    exp_year: $('.card_expiry_year').val()
            }, 
            function(status, response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    payBtn.removeAttr("disabled");
                    $(".payment_errors").html(response.error.message);
                    addInputNames();
                } else {
                    var token = response['id'];
                    //$("#stripeToken").val(token); 
                    var amount = $("#formAmount").val();
                    $.post( 'process.php', {amount:amount, stripeToken:token},function(data){
                        $('#recDiv').html(data);
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;
    });

    // THIS SECTION BELOW DOES NOT GET CALLED
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("cardNumber", Stripe.validateCardNumber, "*");
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("cardCVC", Stripe.validateCVC, "*");
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("cardExpiry", function() {
            return Stripe.validateExpiry($(".card_expiry_month").val(), 
                                                                     $(".card_expiry_year").val())
    }, "*");

    $("#payment_form").validate({
            submitHandler: submit,// this does nothing
            rules: {
                    "card_cvc" : {
                            cardCVC: true,
                            required: true
                    },
                    "card_number" : {
                            cardNumber: true,
                            required: true
                    },
                    "card_expiry_year" : "cardExpiry"
            }
    });
});
```

**This works for validation** but then stripe doesnt work because now i have put the `.post` function, missing all its previous variables from the first example, into this `submitHandler`.

```
$("#payment_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(returnedData) {
                $('#recDiv').append(returnedData);//nothing happens because stripe doesnt work
            } 
        });         
        return false;
    },
        rules: {
                "card_cvc" : {
                        cardCVC: true,
                        required: true
                },
                "card_number" : {
                        cardNumber: true,
                        required: true
                },
                "card_expiry_year" : "cardExpiry"
        }
});
```

**QUESTION:**    How can i get the validation to work from the first sample above?

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", do you get an error message? Does it all appear to go through, but nothing happens? Please clarify that statement.

Comment: post the html code or jsfiddle

Comment: Two things I would look at - first, I don't know how `process.php` expects the data, i.e. serialized or not, etc. Try looking in the network tab of Chrome or similar and see what is actually being `POST`'d and open it up in a browser window to see what comes back. If you're not getting `HTML` that can be appended to `#recDiv` then it's the `PHP` side you have to fix. Second, you have a `return false;` in there after the `$.ajax()` call so no matter what it'll fail validation.

Comment: @Peter `process.php` works fine,  basically i am trying to make a ajax version of this https://gist.github.com/1750368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see you also incorporate this https://gist.github.com/9ce1a97c0453581044bb - if you are using as Mobile / Phonegap, can you show some sample code on how to connect to the backend server?

Comment: connecting to the backend: from first example there is `$.post( 'process.php', {amount:amount, stripeToken:token},function(data){
                        $('#recDiv').html(data);
                    });` which has php from https://gist.github.com/1750375

Comment: but how can i target `$('#paymentBtn').click` in this line `submitHandler:`